# Regular Expressions within a String.split()

Tags: java, regex, split

As the title suggests, this is a question about `Regular Expressions` within a `String.split()` method.

Currently i am parsing lines in from a txt file and into an `ArrayList` using `BufferedReader`. An example of one or two of the lies included within that text file:

> ExampleOne (EXA), 1.382, $
>
> ExampleTwo (EXA), 1.21, £

That `ArrayList` is then being copied to an `Array of Strings` called `parts` and then being split using `String.split()` with the following expression: `\\s*,\\s*`, which gets rid of the commas correctly

```
  for(i=0;i<thing.size();i++) {          
      String[] parts = arrayList.get(i).split("\\s*,\\s*");
  }
```

`parts` is then being simply split into three separate arrays - `currency`, `factor` and `symbol`

Which then produce output as such when printed: `ExampleOne (EXA) 1.382 $` (commas emitted, which i wanted).

However, i would like to also include emitting the following part from each string: `ExampleOne` and the `()` surrounding `EXA` - so that `EXA 1.382 $` is the output.

The pattern i have developed so far does this partially: `.*\\(|nt[A-Z]|\\)\\s*,\\s*` but leaves the second comma as seen: `EXA 1.382, $`, `EXA 1.21, £`

How would i further edit the Expression to also include this functionality and ommit the second comma?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try `.split(".*\\(|\\)?\\s*,\\s*")`

Comment: split on `"[()]|\\s*,\\s*"` since you're just combining anyway.

Comment: If you expect `)` to be followed by a comma, then use this `"\(|\),\s*|\\s*,\\s*"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :). @sln `"\(|\),\s*|\\s*,\\s*"` seems to work partially, however is producing outputs such as; `"ExampleOne EXA 1.382"`, omitting the `"$"`.

Comment: Well, I would use this [\\(|\\)?\s*,\s*](https://regex101.com/r/wZOF16/1) , but even the other one works on your sample.